# Replace the built-in min functions in python

Tags: python, min

I should write a function `min_in_list(munbers)`, which takes a list of
numbers and returns the smallest one. NOTE: built-in function `min` is NOT allowed!

```
def min_in_list(numbers):
    the_smallest = [n for n in numbers if n < n+1]
    return the_smallest
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What don't you like about it?  Does it not run?  Does it get an exception?  Does it produce the wrong answer?  Please provide details if you're going to ask us to help with your homework.  Details matter.  It shows you're learning.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have is that n is *always* less than n + 1 (how could it not be?), so you will get the entire list.

Comment: Did you try it? Here is how it works: 
>>> min_in_list([1,2,3,4,5]) outputs

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Gusto: "Did you try it?".  No.  That's your job.  Please **update** the question with details.  Please **update** the question to say (1) what you want and (2) what you're getting that you don't like.  Details matter.  Please **update** your question with the details.

Comment: Your solution won't work because n is always smaller than n + 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def min_of_two(x, y):
    if x >= y: return x
    else: return y

def min_in_list(numbers):
    return reduce(min_of_two, numbers)
```

You have to produce 1 number from list, not just another list. And this is work for `reduce` function (of course, you can implement it without `reduce`, but by analogy with it).

Comment: @Gusto: yes, but how will you explain to your teacher how you reached that solution?

Comment: @ ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ I don't have to explain anything  - this is a preparation to the exam, and not a 'homework' as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This is almost certainly about as simple as you could make it. You don't even have to give me credit when you turn the assignment in.

```
import itertools
import functools
import operator

def min(seq, keyfun=operator.gt):
    lt = lambda n: functools.partial(keyfun, n)

    for i in seq:
        lti = lt(i)
        try:
            next(itertools.ifilter(lti, seq))
        except:
            return i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min = lambda n: return reduce(lambda x,y: (x>y) and return x or return y,n)
```

Never been tested, use at your own risk.